# Query VARCHAR time range more than 2 hours 0 rows returned?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have a MYSQL table with string of column *time* like below

```
time
-------
8:00:00
8:15:00
8:30:00
8:45:00
```

i am currently having problem in executing query of time range from *n to N*.

it works when i execute query

```
SELECT [column_name] 
FROM [table_name] 
WHERE date= "31-Jul-2018" 
and analytic_id =1 
and  time>="8:00:00" 
and time<="9:00:00";`
```

and return exactly the value from 8 and before 9.

but when i execute the query as below

```
SELECT [column_name] 
FROM [table_name] 
WHERE date= "31-Jul-2018" 
and analytic_id =1 
and  time>="8:00:00" 
and time<="10:00:00";
```

`

it return none.

why is that?

Comment: If you `"sort"` 1 to 10 as string you will get `1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`. That is why 8 to 9 is correct  but <10 is incorrect. cast it to timestamp/time before doing operations

Comment: There is a TIME datatype for a reason.

Comment: Agree with everyone, but you could also say time <= "9:59:59" and get the result you want. It would still elicit criticism when people read your code (and rightly so), but it should work.

Comment: answer from @Slava Rozhnev works for me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prefer solution is convert table column to `TIME` datatype, but if it impossible, You can achieve the result by convert string to time in the query:

```
SELECT [column_name] 
FROM [table_name] 
WHERE
    date = "31-Jul-2018" 
    AND analytic_id = 1 
    AND TIME(time) BETWEEN TIME("8:00:00") AND TIME("10:00:00");
```

[Here you can try it](https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=5ff7d1d868e85df5d6baabe2d0221e67&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: wow this definitely helped me since i cant change the whole database since it is almost complete. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Your WHERE clause is not working like you would be expecting it to work because your *time* field is a *string* type.

String type field will be compared alphabetically here and this is why your WHERE clause results nothing. You are asking those values that comes after "8:00:00" in alphabetical order and before "10:00:00" but "10:00:00" already comes before "8:00:00" when ordered alphabetically so there is nothing in between.

Couple of options for you:

- Store your time in a TIME field 
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html 
   https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-time/
- Convert your *string* typed time into a TIME format dynamically for the comparison to work properly 
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time

Comment: pretty much explained what Slava answer. really helpful thanks!